# JSON Android PHP how to correct error or HOW to DISPLAY the data

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, database

I am new at JSON and in PHP and I know little about Android and I tested this:

**My java code:**

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("QUERY", "SELECT tblWeather.humidity,tblWeather.rainfall,tblWeather.wDate,tblWeather.wTime,tblStations.IMEI, tblStations.Station, tblWeather.IMEI,tblWeather.msgID,tblWeather.tempture FROM tblStations INNER JOIN tblWeather ON tblStations.IMEI = tblWeather.IMEI WHERE tblStations.IMEI= 013226007289958 ORDER BY msgID DESC LIMIT 0,1")); 
            //Add more parameters as necessary

            //Create the HTTP request
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

            //Setup timeouts
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 150000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 150000);          

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://210.14.5.179/aws/getLocal2.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));        
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            // Create a JSON object from the request response
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            //Retrieve the data from the JSON object
            Station = jsonObject.getString("Station");
            tempture = jsonObject.getString("tblWeather.tempture");
```

and I have this PHP code that connects to a web server that gets a QUERY statement from the said code above.

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
if (isset ( $_POST ["QUERY"] ) && $_POST ["QUERY"] != "") {
    /*
     * Following code will list all the products
     */
    $QUERY = $_POST ["QUERY"];

    // array for JSON response
    $response = array ();

    $con = mysqli_connect ( "localhost", "user", "pass", "db" );
    $QUERY = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $con, $QUERY );

    // get all products from products table
    $result = mysqli_query ( $con, $QUERY ) or die ( mysql_error () );

    // check for empty result
    if (mysqli_num_rows ( $result ) > 0) {
        // looping through all results
        // products node
        $response ["tblStations"] = array ();

        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) {
            // temp user array
            $data = array ();
            // $data ["msgID"] = $row ["msgID"];
            $data ["Station"] = $row ["Station"];
            // $product ["IMEI"] = $row ["IMEI"];
            $data ["Date"] = $row ["wDate"];
            $data ["Time"] = $row ["wTime"];
            $data ["temperature"] = $row ["tempture"];
            $data ["humidity"] = $row ["humidity"];
            $data ["rainfall"] = $row ["rainfall"];

            // push single product into final response array
            array_push ( $response ["tblStations"], $data );
        }
        // success
        $response ["success"] = 1;

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode ( $response );
    } else {
        // no products found
        $response ["success"] = 0;
        $response ["message"] = "No products found";

        // echo no users JSON

        echo json_encode ( $response );
       }
       } else {
    echo "Could not complete query. Missing parameter";
      }

      ?>
```

I keep getting this error listed below is my LOG:

```
LOG:

    03-21 14:00:56.552: E/ClientServerDemo(383): Error:
    03-21 14:00:56.552: E/ClientServerDemo(383): org.json.JSONException: No value for        Station
    03-21 14:00:56.552: E/ClientServerDemo(383):    at   org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
    03-21 14:00:56.552: E/ClientServerDemo(383):    at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
    03-21 14:00:56.552: E/ClientServerDemo(383):    at com.oadigital.clientserverrestdemo.MainActivity$DoPOST.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:134)
    03-21 14:00:56.552: E/ClientServerDemo(383):    at com.oadigital.clientserverrestdemo.MainActivity$DoPOST.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
    03-21 14:00:56.552: E/ClientServerDemo(383):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    03-21 14:00:56.552: E/ClientServerDemo(383):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
    03-21 14:00:56.552: E/ClientServerDemo(383):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    03-21 14:00:56.552: E/ClientServerDemo(383):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    03-21 14:00:56.552: E/ClientServerDemo(383):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    03-21 14:00:56.552: E/ClientServerDemo(383):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

I need help please.. Thanks

But when I use `POTMAN-REST` client it will give me an output of this:

```
{"tblStations":[{"Station":"AWS01 - USeP","Date":"2014-03-19","Time":"16:15:01","temperature":"26.9","humidity":"86.4","rainfall":"1.63"}],"success":1}
```

Can anyone tell what is wrong?

Comment: Your Station value is wrapped in the tblStations array. (tblStations.Station)

Comment: can you give me some sample or tutorial about this wrapper object?
or do you have any suggestions on how i can display the data? thanks very much..

Comment: There is a error in doInBackground() method. Also paste the AsyncTask class

Comment: public class DoPOST extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

  Context mContext = null;
  String strNameToSearch = "";
  
  //Result data
  String Station;
  String tempture;
  
  Exception exception = null;
  
  DoPOST(Context context, String nameToSearch){
   mContext = context;
   strNameToSearch = nameToSearch;
  }

  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {

   try{
this is the asynctask class

Comment: @user3315040 Check out my answer it will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

output

```
{"tblStations":[{"Station":"AWS01 - USeP","Date":"2014-03-19","Time":"16:15:01","temperature":"26.9","humidity":"86.4","rainfall":"1.63"}],"success":1}
```

This is how to initialize a JSON parser:

```
//Retrieve the data from the JSON object
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

That will give you the entire string as a Json Object. From there, pull out an individual array as a JsonArray, like this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("tblStations");
```

To access each "Station and temperature " you can use for loop logic:

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
{
JSONObject curr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

String station = curr.getString("Station");
String tempture = curr.getString("temperature");

//Do stuff with the Station and temperature String here
//Add it to a list, print it out, etc.
}
```

Comment: i have a question...
this line: String station = jsonObject.getString("Station");
should it be :String station = curr.getString("Station");??

Comment: i tried it sir, the one that worked was this String tempture = curr.getString("temperature");